# Split Spock specification onto several classes

Tags: java, jersey, spock

I have a Jersey-based RESTfull application which I need to test by calling REST API methods. My specification looks like this:

```
public Test extends Specification {
    def setupSpec(){
        jerseyTest = new JerseyTest(){
            @Override
            protected Application configure() {
                return new App()
            }
        }
        jerseyTest.setUp()
    }

    def cleanupSpec() {
        jerseyTest.tearDown()
    }

    //... feature methods
}
```

Because of I have a lot of feature methods I decided to make above Specification a base class and inherit all other classes from it. To group feature methods in several classes. But in this case my **jerseyTest** object initializes and releases during each separate specification processing. As this takes significant amount of time I need some way to share this object between all specifications. I can do this using some caching factory or static field in base specification but I can't find a way how to determine a moment in time when the last test of the last specification is done and I can call **jerseyTest.tearDown()**.

The main goal is not to have one huge specification class with dozens of feature methods and to have one **jerseyTest** available for all feature methods placed in different classes.

Comment: Unfortunately Spock does not yet support what you are asking. Other people have asked this is a well (i.e. have global setup/teardown for all tests). Perhaps you can open a feature request in the Spock github page